# I don't understand ref unwrapping in the template using TypeScript

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm migrating some Vue3 code from javascript to typescript, and I just can't seem to understand what's going on with the unwrapping of a ref/computed value in the template.
It was my understanding that the template would always auto-unwrap reactive properties, but it doesn't seem to be the case anymore.

Here's my code:

```vue
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from 'vue';

class BaseBlock {
  style = ref('color: black')
}

interface IRefBlockKey {
  [key: string]: BaseBlock;
}

let Block = new BaseBlock();
let refBlock = ref(new BaseBlock());
let refWithKeyBlock = ref({ myBlock: new BaseBlock() });
let refWithInterface = ref<IRefBlockKey>({ myBlock: new BaseBlock() });
</script>

<template>
  <div :style="Block.style">Error in IDE</div>
  <div :style="Block.style.value">No Error</div>
  <div :style="refBlock.style">No Error</div>
  <div :style="refWithKeyBlock['myBlock'].style">No Error (ok...?)</div>
  <div :style="refWithInterface['myBlock'].style">Error in IDE (why now!!)</div>
</template>
```

In both the first and the last `div`, I get an IDE error `Type 'Ref<string>' is not assignable to type 'StyleValue | undefined'.`.
The first div not working is already making me feel very disoriented, but the last one is really a huge "???" for me.

Can anybody point me in the right direction to understand what's going on?

Comment: something important to note: the last line, which gives an error in the IDE, will actually work fine once rendered, while it would break if I added .value

Comment: "Error in IDE (why now!!)" - ask your ide then. The question doesn't make sense in general if it's specific to ide. Which is totally possible because ides have their own toolchain and quirks for the frameworks. But there's a reason for this, and ide is right in this case. ref<IRefBlockKey> type is wrong. ref() unwraps nested refs. This is a reason why the use of classes in vue is discouraged. A class is transformed to a different type when it becomes reactibe. "is already making me feel very disoriented" -  Block is not reactive, nested properties aren't unwrapped in template

Comment: I'm using Volar in vscode. I did "ask the ide then.", but the answer doesn't make a lot of sense to me - maybe you can help? What's different between refWithKeyBlock and refWithInterface? Aren't they virtually the same type? After all, one is `Ref<[key:string]: BaseBlock>`, the other is `Ref<myBlock: BaseBlock>`, where "myBlock" is a string

Comment: The difference is that ref() infers the correct type, and you specify the wrong one in ref<IRefBlockKey>(). This results in `refWithKeyBlock['myBlock'].style` being `Ref` type, which isn't correct because ref() unwraps nested refs and takes this into account when it infers return type. You can debug what the value is at runtime, refWithKeyBlock.myBlock.style is expected to be a string. As said, the primary problem here is a class. VSC is the first thing to blame when you have Vue+TS problem and you don't have it on build but here it's because Vue compiler doesn't check types in templates

Comment: Ok thank you very much. I am trying to refactor my code with composables, but it's not super easy (the code is obviously quite a bit more complicated than shown :D). From the first tests though it SEEMS to circumvent the issue. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction

Comment: Glad it helped.

Comment: I've rolled back your edit. It is not appropriate to edit a solution into your post or add SOLVED. If you've found a solution you want to share, do so by writing an answer to the question in the space provided below for that purpose, as you've now done. It's not necessary to also add it to the question body.

Comment: @KenWhite thank you, I'm sorry! I saw the button to add a solution only afterwards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### SOLUTION

So, there are three possible solutions to this problem.

#### the best one:

refactor everything with composables instead of classes. Using the same code as before, it would become:

```vue
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from 'vue';

function useBaseBlock() {
  style = ref<string>('color: black')
  return { style }
}

type IRefBlockKey = {
  [key: string]: {style: Ref<string> | string};
}

let refWithInterface = ref<IRefBlockKey>({ myBlock: useBaseBlock()});
</script>

<template>
  <div :style="refWithInterface['myBlock'].style">This works now</div>
</template>
```

Note that the type is now `Ref<string> | string` - if you want to wrap the "blocks" using reactive instead of ref, `string` would suffice.

#### the dirty one

Simply wrap `refWithInterface['myBlock'].style` using unref:
`unref(refWithInterface['myBlock'].style)`
White this works, it's certainly not ideal.

#### the don't do this at home one:

The style attribute accepts three types: CSSProperty (technically, a variant of it, depending on the element), string and undefined. You *could* add your type here, for example `Ref<string>` so that the IDE is happy, but this is a horrible solution so... *don't do it!*